# How Can I Schedule Start And Stop for a Node in AudioKit?

Tags: audiokit

Is there a scheduling mechanism for oscillator?

For example, if I want to play 440.0hz sine wave for 2 seconds, do I need to manually start, sleep for 2 seconds, and stop the oscillator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AKSequencer to control other nodes via MIDI.  You can also set timers. It all depends on the amount of accuracy you need.